# How transaction's commit works?

Tags: transactions, rdbms

In my terms 'transaction' handles operations as atomic, say if one fail means all will fail. But what happens when the transaction's commit will fail for some reason?

Consider this:

1. transaction.open
2. insert1
3. insert2
4. transaction.commit

How is this exactly work?

A.2,3 will be performed and if one of them fail, all changes will be reverted from the DB because the lack of 4? In this case if executions of 2,3 were ok but 4 failed, then the whole operation which should succeed will actually fail?

or

B.2,3 wont be performed on db level and if everythings is ok, then 4. will execute the actual commands in the DB?
In this case if 4 fail at halfway of its operation for some reason means that partial -non-atomic- inserts will happen?

or

C.the answer is something different?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes will be made in DB only if all steps are successful and the transaction commit happens successfully too (in your example, the step 4). It’s all or nothing.

Take a look on [ACID](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) transaction properties.

Comment: thanks! 
So then is it possible that successfull insertions will fail just because the commit fails at the end for some reason?

Comment: Yes. Everything will fail. It’s important to know too that in the case of fail in step 4 the transaction can continue existing, possibly holding locks and blocking resources.

Comment: But: Normally after a reasonable timeout which can be defined at the DBMS-Server, such a hanging transaction should become rolled back by itself.